# get the value of <param> in <object> with selenium IE driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

the html like the follow:

```
<OBJECT id="IndiDocX" CODEBASE="/IndiDoc.CAB#version=4,5,0,132" width=500 height=201 VIEWASTEXT>
.........
<PARAM NAME="IDNUM" VALUE="4090">
<PARAM NAME="Editable" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="Nodelfiles" VALUE="\adad.xlsx\1111.sep\2222.gw">
```

I want get the value of `PARAM[@name="Nodelfiles"]` with xpath in IE driver
my code:

```
attr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//object[@id="IndiDocX"]/param[@name="Nodelfiles"]').get_attribute('value')
```

message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Dropbox\17.Develop\5.Projects\auto.oa\main.py", line 158, in <module>
    main()
  File "e:\Dropbox\17.Develop\5.Projects\auto.oa\main.py", line 154, in main
    insert_to_db('DC5EF2F7F4DB79E648258523002C628E')
  File "e:\Dropbox\17.Develop\5.Projects\auto.oa\main.py", line 138, in insert_to_db
    attr = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 139, in get_attribute
    attributeValue = self.parent.execute_script(
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Error executing JavaScript
```

How can get the value of 
I use this can be get it by index,but not name

```
js = 'return document.getElementById("IndiDocX").getElementsByTagName("PARAM")[24].getAttribute("value");'
attr = driver.execute_script(js)
print(attr)
```

the 24 is index

Answer (score 1):

use diriver.page_souce to gei html，and user re.findall() to match the data